# Django class based views: page "GET" content disappears after "POST" request is executed

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am building a homepage that has a dynamically updated blogs section and a BMI calculator section. Initially, the page loads perfectly fine. But the problem is that when I calculate the BMI (POST request) the page refreshes and the blogs section (GET) disappears.

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeViews.as_view(), name='home_page'),
]
```

my views.py

```
class HomeViews(ListView, View):
    template_name="home_page.html"    
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts_diet = BlogModel.objects.filter(cat__title='Healthy Diet').order_by('-created_at')[:1]
        return render(request, 'home_page.html', {
            'posts_diet' : posts_diet,
        })
        
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST": 
            # get input
            height_metric = request.POST.get("height-metric")
            weight_metric = request.POST.get("weight-metric")
            #----bmi Formula-----
            if height_metric:
                bmi = float(weight_metric) / (float(height_metric)**2)
        else:
            bmi = 0

        return render(request, 'home_page.html', {
            'bmi': bmi,
            })
```

my home_page.html

```
<div>
  {% for pst in posts_diet %}
  <div>
    <img src="uploads/{{ pst.blog_main_image }}" />
    <div>
      <p>{{ pst.cat | striptags | slice:':50' }}</p>
      <p>{{ pst.created_at | date:"M d, Y" |striptags | safe }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ pst.title | striptags | slice:':150' }}</h1>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

my terminal:

```
# initial homepage request (everything loads perfectly fine) 
[24/Dec/2021 14:34:21] "GET /static/css/dist/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 30992
[24/Dec/2021 14:34:21,606] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 65275)

# on submitting POST request GET gets executed but GET content is not displayed
[24/Dec/2021 14:34:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44233
[24/Dec/2021 14:34:42] "GET /static/css/dist/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 30992
[24/Dec/2021 14:35:41] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 37434
```

I think I can get away with this issue by using AJAX for form submission but that might not be a robust solution.
Kindly advise ...

Comment: Hello bro did you find solution ?

Comment: I am currently using AJAX for this but I think this will be solved altering views.py post method by executing lookup of 'post_diet' variable from db just as it has been done is get method. Basically on POST request page reloads so have to lookup db again and provide template with the data to render.